# How to wait a ExtJS Panel to render before expand?

Tags: extjs4, panel, expand

I have an `infoContainer` extending an `Ext.panel.Panel` in ExtJS 4.0.7 with these properties (only relevant shown):

- collapsible: true
- collapsed: true
- disabled: true
- forceLayout: true

I've some modifications (some render) to apply on components (like textfields, checkboxes, etc), so I do this in the `beforeexpand` of the panel.  But, when the panel expands, we clearly see modifications on components after the panel is visible.  So, I need this logic to be complete **before** we see the panel open.

So, can I restrict the expand of the panel to happen only when the logic of `beforeexpand` is done? and how to do this?

Comment: Does the rendering logic need to be different every time this panel expands? Or is it just once after the application loads?

Comment: Once, the first time the panel expands.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it:

Create a function that does the rendering/modification logic which you currently want to occur on the `beforeexpand` event.

In this function, set a custom property on the panel so you will know that it is rendered/modified according to your logic e.g. `myPanel.isPrepared = true;`.

Also, at the very end of this function do another call to `myPanel.expand();`

Then, in the `beforeexpand` handler put a conditional that checks if your rendering/modifications have been done e.g, `if (myPanel.isPrepared) {...`

If it passes, then don't do anything in the handler and let the panel expand.

If it does *not* pass then call the function mentioned above and then `return false;` that will stop the panel from expanding, your function will do the needed rendering/modification you wanted and then it will call expand when it is all done.

Assuming that you are not creating your app with the MVC pattern the handler and function could look something like this:

```
myPanel.on('beforeexpand`, function() {
    if (!myPanel.isPrepared) {
        prepareMyPanel();
        return false;
    }
})

function prepareMyPanel() {
    // rendering / modification logic here...
    myPanel.isPrepared = true;
    myPanel.expand();
}
```

If you are creating your app with MVC pattern you should be able to translate that over to the right controller handlers.

Comment: I understand the logic behind this answer and it is well explained, tried it many ways, but for me it does not work.

Comment: @elbaid are you getting any kind of error message? is the `prepareMyPanel` function getting called at all? could you post the code you tried?

Comment: There's no error message, just not working, events don't get fired in order I want.